# TouchableOpacity inside 'absolute' positioned view

Tags: react-native, z-index, stylesheet, absolute, touchableopacity

I have following view

```js
  <FlatList
      style={{marginTop: 5,
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      borderRadius: 5, backgroundColor: ACTIVITY_BACKGROUND_COLOR}}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
      extraData={this.state.suggestions}
      listKey={(item, index)=>index.toString()}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      horizontal={false}
      data={this.state.suggestions}
      keyExtractor={(index)=>index}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => {
           return (
                 <TouchableOpacity
                 onPress={()=>console.log('pressed')}
                 style={{paddingHorizontal: 10,
                 paddingTop: 5}}>
                       <Text
                       style={[styles.labelText, {
                              color: PRIMARY_COLOR,
                              marginVertical: 5,
                              backgroundColor:ACTIVITY_BACKGROUND_COLOR}]}>{item.description}</Text>
                       </TouchableOpacity>
                      );}}
     />
```

`TouchableOpacity` dosen't seem to work inside 'absolute' positioned `Flatlist` in `Android`. How ever it works on `IOS`. I have tried adding `zIndex` and all but it has no effect and `TouchableOpacity` is not clickable. Any reason for this behaviour?

Comment: This may be because of the status line height.

Comment: Can you explain a bit. Do you mean the lineheight for Text component?

Comment: Your list is at the top of your cell phone. The area can be a status line area. In other words, the status line and your list may overlap.

Comment: Ohh...No it is not overlapping for sure. As soon as i remove position: 'absolute' it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, if you remove the position, the direction you set  work. So your list is in Safe Area. However, if you set the position, your list may be in the status line outside the Safe Area.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try using react-native-geasture-handler. It worked for me.

`import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';`